# How can I enable firefox 44+ extension without verify (signing)?

Tags: firefox-addon

Since the firefox 44, all firefox extensinos must to sign. Is there any workaround to turn their on without verify?

It will required for me for this reasons:
1. Develop extensions with scheme: write some code, fix bug -> reinstall, test -> write some code, fix bug -> ...
2. Corporate extensions - I cant't to public this, beacause these extensions are only for company employees.

They are work fine on firefox 41 , but this browser version is now too old for users, which are my company employees.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Switch to either FF ESR or FF developer edition. Extended Support version still has ability to use unsigned plugins. Developer edition can be side-installed with normal FF and there you can enable unsigned extensions in about:config.

Comment: Is it this? http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox-developer-portable . Thanks, cool! And about ESR, can you give me a link - how to do this?

Comment: Thanks, I'he found https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/organizations/all/

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer preferences - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/devprefs/ - and then it should work as you expect in Firefox Dev Edition and Firefox Nightly. It may work as expected in Firefox beta and release, I haven't tested it. As last resort you can always go to about:debugging and click "load temporary addon".